# How can i setup Liferay 6.2 tomcat8 server configuration in eclipse or liferay studio? Is it supportable?

Tags: eclipse, server, tomcat8, liferay-6.2

Actually i am not able to configure tomcat8 server in eclipse or liferay studio as liferay plugin is showing only 6.2 with tomcat7 option not 6.2 with tomcat8.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUCc7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Liferay's 6.2 Compatibility Matrix](https://web.liferay.com/documents/14/21598941/Liferay+Portal+6.2+EE+Compatibility+Matrix.pdf), it looks like Tomcat 8 is a supported EE configuration when patched to SP15+.

I'd imagine that using a Tomcat 8 server with Liferay would be simpler in their   studio than with basic Eclipse, and could probably be accomplished by:

1. Setting up a manual installation on an existing Tomcat 8 server
   (that you've configured) using the Liferay .war (detailed steps [can
   be found here](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/6-2/deploy/-/knowledge_base/d/installing-liferay-on-tomcat-7))
2. Creating a [new Liferay Workspace in Dev
   Studio](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-0/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/creating-a-liferay-workspace-with-liferay-ide), but deselect the "Download Liferay bundle" checkbox when
   creating the workspace, and configure the workspace’s
   gradle.properties file to point to the pre-existing bundle by
   setting the liferay.workspace.home.dir property.

Alternatively, you could [set up Liferay's Plugins SDK](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/6-2/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/setting-up-the-plugins-sdk) to be used with your Liferay version/application server of choice.

If you already have existing projects in Eclipse, though, you could probably modify the [steps in this article](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/6-2/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/developing-apps-with-liferay-ide) to use a 6.2 Liferay .war with Tomcat 8 in Eclipse.

Comment: Hi Wilson,You mis-understood my question. The question is, Under eclipse we will be having server tab right. How we will configure with liferay 6.2 with tomcat8 combination? only shows liferay 6.2 with tomcat7. Let me know whether it is achievable or not?